# How to show $F(\vec{x})$ is lipschitz on $[0,1] \times [0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, continuity

We know that $f(x)=x^2$ is lipschitz on [0,1]; intuitively the steepest the graph of $f$ gets is at $x=1$, and I can find the lipschitz constant by a simple factoring argument.

Now say $\theta=(x,y,z)$ and $F(\theta)=(x(x+y+z),0)$. Intuitively, I think this function should be lipschitz as well, but I can't seem to figure out how to prove it. Suppose I'm using the euclidean norm.

$||F(\theta)-F(\theta')||= \sqrt{[x(x+y+z)-x'(x'+y'+z')]^2}...$ n.t.s. $...\leq K \sqrt{(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2+(z-z')^2}$

and I can't figure out how to get there. All attempts have failed so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**hint**

> $$\sqrt{(xy-x'y')^2}=\sqrt{((x-x')y+(y-y')x')^2}$$
>    $$\leq\sqrt{2(((x-x')y)^2+((y-y')x')^2)}$$
>    $$\leq\sqrt{2}\sqrt{(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2}$$

And $0\leq{x}\leq{1},0\leq{y}\leq{1}$

> **By using $(a+b)^2\leq{2(a^2+b^2)}$**

Comment: oops I mis-wrote the question, but this hint may still work for the  edited one. I'll take a look.

Comment: yay applying the "by using" trick 3 times, worked for the edited problem ... teach a man to fish. I'd vote up the answer if I had enough rep to do so.